# Divide by zero encountered in true_divide while fitting GMMHMM hmmlearn model

Tags: python, time-series, hmmlearn

I am trying to train an **gmmhmm** with the **hmmlearn** model with multi-variate timeseries of 25 features in the following way:

```
hmm_g = hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=4, n_mix=2).fit(X, lengths)
```

where `X` is an array with shape `(timeseries_dataset_length, 25)` containing all the  timeseries in a sigle array,

and `lengths` is an array with shape `(timeseries_dataset_length, 1)` containing the lengths of each time series. As it is specified in the docs.

It works correctly if I run the code with `n_components=2` but if change the **gmmhmm** params to `n_components=4, n_mix=2` I've got the following error:

```
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\hmm.py:1052: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
self.covars_ = c_n / c_d
```

As it is a warning, I've tryed to compute afterwards the `score` of a time series but I've gott the following error:

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\base.py", line 644, in check_sum_1
raise ValueError(
ValueError: startprob must sum to 1 (got nan)
```

And this is beacuse after the *divide by zero error* the `startprob_` and the `transmat_` **gmmhmm** class variables became `nan`.

And I don't really understand why is this happening.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the following line in the last line of `_do_mstep` function (hmm.py line 1052) it work's correctly.

```
self.covars_ = c_n / c_d + self.min_covar
```

Previously it was:

```
self.covars_ = c_n / c_d
```

Comment: My problem is exactly like yours. I am approaching your solution.